# Visual Studio Installer - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio, installation

Whenever I try to launch the Visual Studio 2015 installer, I immediately get the following error message:

[image: Error]

I've tried redownloading the installer, but for the life of me I can't seem to get it to install. Would anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You could run a tool such as procmon https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx to catch what file is missing. That may help diagnose the cause of the problem.

Comment: Disable the antivirus and try again.

Comment: The same problem with me. After unsuccesfull unistall of VS2015 programs from Control Panel. It seems that C++ runtime enivironment missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- My first suggestion would be to try and create a new user, download the installer again and see if it works;
- As mentioned in the comments, [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) may help diagnose your problem;
- Your **antivirus** may consider the installer a false positive, so you may want to temporary **disable** it before you download the installer again;
- Make sure your installer is the **real** one. Here is the link for the [Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409) version;
- There is also the possibility that the disk is failing. Try running `chkdsk` on your drive.

**EDIT**:
The problem seemed to be about the web installer, try grabbing the `vs2015.com_enu.iso` file available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).

Comment: Creating a new user didn't seem to work and I don't have antivirus running currently. I did download from visualstudio.com, so I decided to run process monitor. There seems to be a few "NAME NOT FOUND" errors when trying to access some registry keys, but I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem or how to solve it. I'm currently running chkdsk and I will report back after it is finished. If you'd like to see some of the keys that are missing, I'd be glad to share.

Comment: NAME NOT FOUND is not an uncommon result for an operation.  Perhaps an app is probing for the existence of a file or setting, and would take a different code path depending on its presence.  Perhaps the app is built to be configured with reasonable defaults that accommodate a majority of scenarios, but can be "tweaked" via registry settings.  If it doesn't check for them, it won't know they exist. [source](http://forum.sysinternals.com/name-not-found-a-very-frequent-result_topic19467.html)

Comment: Do you encounter the same error when trying to install other versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: Nope, it only seems to be 2015; 2013 installed fine.

Comment: Would you like to download `vs2015.com_enu.iso` then? Maybe the web installer is not recognized or something. Link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146)

Comment: Glad it finally worked, enjoy your new IDE :) (edited my answer accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was that the user temp directory was inacessible due to a disk issue (my temp dir was on a small dedicated SSD disk).

Without access to temp dir, VS crashes on startup and installers won't run.

I had to change my temp dir (from environment variables) and VS started again.